# Probleme encoding characters with Python 2.7

Tags: python, database, encoding

It works fine with regular characters but it doesn't work with
accented characters like é,à etc...
Here is the program:

```
def search():
    connection = sqlite3.connect('vocab.sqlite')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT   French, English value FROM Ami "
    cursor.execute(sql)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    data=sorted(data)
    file_open=open('vraiamis.html','w')
    for i in data:
       a='<a href="'+'http://www.google.fr/#hl=fr&gs_nf=1&cp=4&gs_id=o&xhr=t&q='
       a=a+str(i[0]).encode('latin-1')+'">'+str(i[0]).encode('latin-1')+'</a>'+'<br>'
       file_open.write(a)

 file_open.close()
 webbrowser.open('vraiamis.html')
```

when the value in the database contains special characters like é,à,ç ( it doesn't work I get the following error message:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
a=a+i[0].encode('latin-1')+'">' + i[0].encode('latin-1')+'</a>'+'<br>'
```

etc - your `str()` calls are trying to convert the unicode to a bytestring before you've decoded it.

Answer (score 0):

You may write your `vraiamis.html` in `utf-8` encoding, so that your special characters may be encoded.

```
def search():
    import codecs
    connection = sqlite3.connect('vocab.sqlite')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT   French, English value FROM Ami "
    cursor.execute(sql)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    data=sorted(data) 
    file_open= codecs.open('vraiamis.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    for i in data:
       a=u'<a href="' + u'http://www.google.fr/#hl=fr&gs_nf=1&cp=4&gs_id=o&xhr=t&q='
       a=a + i[0] + u'">' + i[0] + u'</a>' + u'<br>'
       file_open.write(a)
    file_open.close()
    webbrowser.open('vraiamis.html')
```

Comment: Sorry but the encoding doesn't work it returns an error message